# PDO prepare NOT IN or <> multi language

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

For few hours i am struggling to do make this work.
Ok i have two languages in first case in url are no variable ?lang= it is the base language and the function that checks for language variable lang,Do, if the variable in url exists,and whatever its value is, set global variable $lang to "en" else to NULL. Now i got in database i have column lang and i now need to get data out of it. The public variable if is true means that i need to get all subjects that are pulic and in database column "visible" value is 2. If not Visible than value is 1.

1. get all public items that are visible that don't have value "en" in row lang
2. get all public items that are visible if lang != NULL (if in row lang is value "en"
3. get all items if public == false && lang == null get all rows that got visible 2 and lang column is empty
4. get all items if public == false && lang != null get all items if in column lang is value "en". That's all i need. But mysteriously its not working.
   My code.

   ```
   function get_all_subjects($public = true,$lang = NULL){
   $db = connect_db();
   $query = "SELECT * "; 
   $query .= "FROM subjects ";
   if($public && $lang == NULL){
       $query .= "WHERE visible =:visible ";
       $query .= "AND WHERE lang =:lang ";
   }elseif($public && $lang != NULL){
       $query .= "WHERE visible =:visible ";
       $query .= "AND WHERE lang =:lang ";
   }elseif(!$public && $lang != NULL){
       $query .= "WHERE lang =:lang ";
   }elseif(!$public && $lang == NULL){
       $query .= "AND WHERE lang =:lang ";
   }
   $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
   if($public && $lang == NULL){
       $stmt->bindValue(':visible', 2, PDO::PARAM_INT);
       $stmt->bindParam(':lang',$lang, PDO::PARAM_STR);
   }elseif($public && $lang != NULL){
       $stmt->bindValue(':visible', 2, PDO::PARAM_INT);
       $stmt->bindParam(':lang',$lang, PDO::PARAM_STR);
   }elseif(!$public && $lang != NULL){
       $stmt->bindParam(':lang',$lang, PDO::PARAM_STR);
   }elseif(!$public && $lang == NULL){
       $stmt->bindParam(':lang',$lang, PDO::PARAM_STR);
   }
    if($stmt->execute()){
   return $stmt;
    }else{
   return NULL;
   }
   }
   ```

   I think in need to put in NOT IN :lang or <>:lang or != but i don't now... Nothing works my head hurts and i am tired.

Edited. Works only public and !public "versions" in "en". In base language public = true and public = false i got error Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object that is in other function where i call this on. on line 2
I i think i know.. I need NOT IN, in first if statement for :lang. But how?
`$all_subjects = get_all_subjects($public,$lang);
$subject = $all_subjects->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
A bit of study mysql

```
function get_all_subjects($public = true,$lang = NULL){
    $db = connect_db();
    $query = "SELECT * "; 
    $query .= "FROM subjects ";
    if($public && $lang == NULL){
        $query .= "WHERE NOT lang =:lang ";
        $query .= " AND visible =:visible ";
    }elseif($public && $lang != NULL){
        $query .= "WHERE visible =:visible ";
        $query .= "AND lang =:lang ";
    }elseif(!$public && $lang != NULL){
        $query .= "WHERE lang =:lang ";
    }elseif(!$public && $lang == NULL){
        $query .= " WHERE NOT lang =:lang ";
    }
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    if($public && $lang == NULL){
        $stmt->bindValue(':visible', 2, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindValue(':lang','en', PDO::PARAM_STR);
    }elseif($public && $lang != NULL){
        $stmt->bindValue(':visible', 2, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(':lang',$lang, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    }elseif(!$public && $lang != NULL){
        $stmt->bindParam(':lang',$lang, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    }elseif(!$public && $lang == NULL){
        $stmt->bindValue(':lang','en', PDO::PARAM_STR);
    }
if($stmt->execute()){
    return $stmt;
}else{
    return NULL;
}
```

}